# Bind css class to the current uiRouter state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know about existing `ui-sref-active` directive, but in my case i'm changing state internally using `$state.go("")`, so this directive won't work for my. I've also tried to write it as `ng-class="{active: vm.isOpened()}"`, but it throws `TypeError: boolean is not a function`. Any other ways to do this?

**Update**

I dont understand why this error occures, cause the `isOpened` is a method:

```
self.isOpened = function() { return ContentManager.isCurrent('appMenu'); };
```

Comment: according to that error is telling you that isOpened is a variable, not  a function just remove the () after isOpened and try that

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the solution would be to remove calling braces `()` from the html code, but not because it's not a function, but a variable. It seems that in this case when angular sees a function in case like this, it invokes it automatically, hence was the error.